# Readline.H history usage in C

Tags: c, readline

I'm trying to get the last command to write inside of my C program. Right now It is just taking a command and adding it to history.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<readline/readline.h>
#include<readline/history.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *s;
    char *p = getenv("USER");
    char *host =getenv("HOSTNAME"); 
    int count = 1;
    char *ps;
    sprintf(ps, "%d %s@%s:", count, p, host);


    while (s=readline(ps)){
        add_history(s);
        free(s);
        count++;
        sprintf(ps, "%d %s@%s:", count, p, host);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I see from the manual located here https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html That I'm unable to get information from history without using Function:

```
HIST_ENTRY * history_get (int offset)
```

Does anyone have an example of `readline` history? I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around this concept.

Thank you

Comment: `sprintf(ps, "%d %s@%s:", count, p, host);` will invoke undefined behavior, since you have not allocated any space for the pointer `ps`.

Comment: How much storage is available to `ps`? Have you looked at `struct _hist_entry` and `struct _hist_state` (typedeffed to `HIST_ENTRY` and `HISTORY_STATE`)? [**2. Programming with GNU History**](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html#SEC6) looks to be a decent description of the library use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, your primary issue was you provided only an *uninitialized pointer* with no memory allocated for `ps`. While you are free to dynamically allocate `ps`, simply using automatic storage is sufficient, e.g.:

```
char ps[MAXC] = "";  /* where MAXC is a constant of sufficient size */
```

In addition to getting a single entry, the readline and history library provides the ability to retrieve the entire history list for a session. For example to retrieve a history session, `history_list ()` will return an allocated array of type `HIST_ENTRY **` containing the history for the session. A short example of its use would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<readline/readline.h>
#include<readline/history.h>

enum { MAXC = 128 };

int main (void){

    char ps[MAXC] = "", 
        *p = getenv("USER"),
        *host = getenv("HOSTNAME"),
        *s = NULL; 
    int count = 1;
    sprintf(ps, "%d %s@%s> ", count, p, host);

    using_history();    /* initialize history */

    while ((s = readline(ps))) {
        if (strcmp (s, "quit") == 0) {
            free (s);
            break;
        }
        add_history (s);
        free (s);
        count++;
        sprintf (ps, "%d %s@%s> ", count, p, host);
    }

    /* get the state of your history list (offset, length, size) */
    HISTORY_STATE *myhist = history_get_history_state ();

    /* retrieve the history list */
    HIST_ENTRY **mylist = history_list ();

    printf ("\nsession history for %s@%s\n\n", p, host);
    for (int i = 0; i < myhist->length; i++) { /* output history list */
        printf (" %8s  %s\n", mylist[i]->line, mylist[i]->timestamp);
        free_history_entry (mylist[i]);     /* free allocated entries */
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    free (myhist);  /* free HIST_ENTRY list */
    free (mylist);  /* free HISTORY_STATE   */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readline
1 david@alchemy> command 1
2 david@alchemy> command 2
3 david@alchemy> command 3
4 david@alchemy> quit

session history for david@alchemy

 command 1
 command 2
 command 3
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks David, It helps me understand this much more. My end goal is being able to user input 5 and see the 5th command. Thanks for helping, i truly see how to use this because the manual was just confusing me.

Comment: Hello, I run your code with valgind and I saw some "still reachable"  blocks at exit. Can you modify your answer to eliminate them so everyone that uses this code does not have memory leaks?

Comment: @GeorgeSp if you run `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` you wil find all the memory what was not freed was memory allocated and managed by the `readline` library and not my code. All of the memory allocated in the above code (to which a valid pointer exists that could be passed to `free()`) was properly freed. There is no `valgrind` exclusion for the `readline` library that would mask the memory it allocates. Many libraries manager their own memory and simply rely on program exit to free it (bad practice -- but more a result of library initialization)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you are right, I had just found out the same and I was about to write edit my comment. Thank you for the reply on this old question.

Comment: Happens `:)` `valgrind` is a great tool, but it relies on *"exclusion"* files to mask memory allocated by the system and system libraries. (even newer versions of `valgrid` don't always catch all memory allocated by the system). When you are using libraries in addition to the `libc` it is hit-or-miss (mostly miss) on whether the memory allocated by the library will be masked. Some OS's like for raspberrypi -- don't even have good exclusion files for `libc`... There is a way you can generate custom exclusion files (I tried, but haven't had much luck) Maybe you'll fair better.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the count of the current (last) entry with `int where_history(void)`. With your example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<readline/readline.h>
#include<readline/history.h>
#include <string.h>

// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!

int main()
{
  char *s;
  char *p = getenv("USER");
  char *host = getenv("HOSTNAME");
  int count = 1;
  char *ps;

  printf("USER: %s\n", p);
  // HOSTNAME does not return anything here, so I skipped it
  printf("HOST: %s\n", host);

  // restricting to 32/64 bit ints for simplicity
  size_t size_int = (sizeof(int) == 4) ? 10 : 20;
  //         env(USER)    env(HOSTN...)   log_10(MAX_INT)  " @:\0"  angst-allowance
  //ps = malloc(strlen(p) + strlen(host) +      size_int       + 4          + 1);
  //sprintf(ps, "%d %s@%s:", count, p, host);
  ps = malloc(strlen(p) + size_int + 4 + 1);
  sprintf(ps, "%d %s:", count, p);

  while ((s = readline(ps)) != NULL) {
    add_history(s);
    free(s);
    count++;
    sprintf(ps, "%d %s:", count, p);
  }

  printf("\nlastline:\n");
  // That's the line you were looking for, I think.
  // int where_history(void) returns the current (that is: last) line
  // HIST_ENTRY *history_get (int) returns the entry data set
  HIST_ENTRY *entry = history_get(where_history());

  printf("%s\n", entry->line);
  free(ps);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```